# Area included in the curves

Tags: area

What is the area included in the curves

√x + √|y| = 1 and |x| + |y| = 1.

I know the area the total area of the |x| + |y| = 1 is 2 units square but i cannot determine the area of the given first curve .. Please help.

Comment: I think you can use symmetry and only analyse the first quadrant ($x>0$ and $y>0$)

Comment: @PeterForeman Area common in between these two curves

Comment: @PeterForeman Can we calculate the total area like calculate in first quadrant and rest of them by symmetry ?

Comment: @MattiP. Sorry but can you help me how to calculate the area in the first quadrant in these curves ?

Comment: For the second one, I would use symmetry. If we only consider $x,y>0$ then the equation reduces to $x+y=1$ or $y=1-x$. This is just a triangle with side lengths $1\times 1$, giving an area of $\frac{1}{2}\times 1 \times 1$. So going back, symmetry gives us four of these, making the total area $4 \times \frac{1}{2}= 2$.

Comment: @MattiP. Okay but what about the first equation with the √|y| ?

Comment: here is the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6tia2ucets), however, it is not clear which included area is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $$x\geq 0$$ we get
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{|y|}=1$$ and $$x+|y|=1$$ and you can compute $y$

Comment: Thank you sir i got the anwers.. By the way is the answer 1/3 sq. Units ?

Answer (score 1):

The branch of $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}=1$ in the first quadrant is
$$
y=(1-\sqrt{x})^2=1-2\sqrt{x}+x
$$
The area under it is
$$
\int_0^1(1-2\sqrt{x}+x)\,dx
$$
The area under the line $x+y=1$ (from $x=0$ to $x=1$) is…

Subtract and multiply by $4$.